# S22.IMAP does not always read attachments

Tags: c#, asp.net, imap, attachment, gmail-imap

I use the [S22.IMAP](https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap) library as follows:

```
using (ImapClient client = new ImapClient(imap, 993,
                   usuario, psw, AuthMethod.Login, true))
{
    foreach (var uid in client.Search(SearchCondition.Unseen()))
    {
        var message = client.GetMessage(uid);                      
        foreach (Attachment atc in message.Attachments)
        { 
            if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(atc.Name) == ".xml")
            {
                String archivoXML_texto = "";
                byte[] allBytes = new byte[atc.ContentStream.Length];
                int bytesRead = atc.ContentStream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)atc.ContentStream.Length);
                using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(allBytes))
                {
                    StreamReader archivoXML = new StreamReader(memory);
                    archivoXML_texto = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
                    archivoXML.Close();
                    memory.Dispose();
                }
                .......
                .......
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a problem: when I try to read the attachment of some mail,
I realize in the debugging of the code that is not reading the attachment.
The strange thing about this event is that it happens with some emails, as well as gmail and private emails (I do not say that all of these domains do not read the attachments), the others read them well.

**Questions:**

1. I would like to know what would be the cause that prevents me from reading these emails. Could it be that there is some privacy settings, for example in gmail that makes it block the attachments in the code?
2. If this were true, how would you enable it? Or should I change the way the code is implemented?
3. And what would be the best or some good example?

Comment: Before u get any downvotes,please edit/approve existing edits for your post for better explanation of your problem.Firstly,the `Title` is totally wrong.It should rather be `Cannot red attachments using MailKit`.Moving on to your question,you main question has a lot of flaws as well which can't be described in comments.As far as i see it,u are using `ImapClient` class which is either a part of `ImapX` or MailKit` but in your case,it's `MailKit` which u should've added atleast in the `Tags`.However,to troubleshoot,go [here](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#SaveAttachments)

Comment: He's not using MailKit, he's using S22.Imap.

Comment: IMAP makes it difficult or impossible to write any such privacy features. Clients either have access to all parts of a message or none. But if you're using some sort of braindamaged virus protection thing, that might be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using (var client = new ImapClient ()) {
            client.Connect ("imap.gmail.com", 993, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
            client.Authenticate ("mailo@gmail.com", "password");
            client.Inbox.Open(FolderAccess.ReadWrite);
            var uids = client.Inbox.Search(SearchQuery.NotSeen);

            foreach (var uid in uids)
            {
                var message = client.Inbox.GetMessage(uid);
                client.Inbox.AddFlags(uid, MessageFlags.Seen, true);
                foreach (var attachment in message.Attachments.OfType<MimePart>())
                {
                    if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(attachment.FileName) == ".xml")
                    {
                        byte[] allBytes = new byte[attachment.Content.Stream.Length];
                        int bytesRead = attachment.Content.Stream.Read(allBytes, 0, (int)attachment.Content.Stream.Length);
                        string texto_definitivo = "";
                        String archivoXML_textoBase64 = "";
                        using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream(allBytes))
                        {
                            StreamReader archivoXML = new StreamReader(memory);
                            archivoXML_textoBase64 = archivoXML.ReadToEnd();
                            byte[] temp_backToBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(archivoXML_textoBase64);
                            texto_definitivo = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(temp_backToBytes);
                            archivoXML.Close();
                            memory.Dispose();
                        }   

                    }      
                }
            }
            client.Disconnect (true);
        }
```

It could be better in converting the text that is like base64 into string. It would be ideal if the content of the text of the attachment is obtained directly, without making conversions to byte [], byte [] to string the content of the attachment (for some strange reason is the string in base64), from string base64 to byte [ ], and from byte [] to string.

If someone has a better solution, it would be spectacular.